# Chain-processing stream of data

Tags: php, stream, pipe

In my app, I need to generate rather large zip archives, and to store them encrypted for security reasons.

I have found a way to do so using streams so as to reduce the amount of RAM required and so far this is working rather well. I've piped ZipStream's output to an OpenSSL process call and that gives me the result I want, using the following code:

```php
$cmd = "openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -K $myKey -iv $myIv -out $myFile";
$pipesStructure = [0 => array("pipe", "r"), 1 => array("pipe", "w"), 2 => array("pipe", "w")];
$process = proc_open($cmd, $pipesStructure, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    $zipOptions = new Archive();
    $zipOptions->setOutputStream($pipes[0]);
    $zip = new ZipStream('archive.zip', $zipOptions);

    foreach($myFiles as $f) {
        $zip->addFile($f->name, $f->content);
    }

    $zip->finish();

    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
}
```

*Now*, I would like, while I do all that, to compute the hash of the unencrypted zip archive. The idea is to insert an additional "processing block" through which the stream would pass:

```
[ ZipStream ] -----> [ Hash computing ] -----> [ Encryption ] ------> Final output
```

But so far I'm unable to understand well enough how streams work and I'm failing to achieve that...
I'm pretty sure I need to use `hash_init`, `hash_update_stream`, and `hash_final`, but I can't seem to be able to "feed" the data to `hash_update_stream`.

I've initialized a hash context and added the following code *before* the loop that adds all files to the zip, hoping `hash_update_stream` would merely read what goes through `$pipes[0]`, but apparently that's not the way to do it

```
...
hash_update_stream($hashContext, $pipes[0]);
...
```

Upon "finalizing" the hash, the output is the hash of an empty string (`''`)

Any pointers as to how to proceed?